# Visual Studio Test task partially succeeds instead of failing when some tests fail

Tags: azure-devops

The [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) partially succeeds thus the stage of the pipeline also partially succeeds, but I want the stage to fail if any tests fail(but wait until all test run).
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio Test task partially succeeds instead of failing when
> some tests fail

This could be because you have **selected** "Continue Error" under "Control Options".

[image]

According to the document [How to: Ignore errors in tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-ignore-errors-in-tasks?view=vs-2019):

> The ContinueOnError attribute of the Task element controls whether a
> build stops or continues when a task failure occurs. **This attribute
> also controls whether errors are treated as errors or warnings when
> the build continues**.

Comment: It did work but it is very confusing, because in literal sense this setting should stop test run immediately on failed test but it doesn't which is great, but the wording is bad.